# Move to the end of line character in Vi, past the last character in the line

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

How come in Vi, when I hit `$`, it goes to the last character in the line instead of the end of the line character? How would I go to the end of the line character in one keystroke, and what is the fastest way to delete the end of the line character?

Comment: Do you mean the newline?

Comment: If you do mean the newline, it sounds like you want to join lines. Hitting J anywhere on the line will delete the newline.

Comment: @Michealtwofish: You should have posted this as an answer...

Comment: @sum1stolemyname It was really a follow up to Mark's question, and Aristotle's is a more complete answer anyway :)

Comment: Also check out `:help 've'`, setting which to `onemore` will allow one to position the cursor after the last character. However, that's not perfect, because, for instance,  `>  still works inconsistently if the end of selection was at the last character on the line :(

Comment: Hmm... now it seems to work consistently again! :) Either I messed up when I wrote that or this is due to the different machine/setup that I'm using right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How come in Vi, when I hit `$`, it goes to the last character in the line instead of the end of the line character?

Because that’s sufficient for anything you might want to achieve.

> How would I go to the end of the line character in one keystroke

You basically never need to. You just do different things in the next step depending on what you wanted to achieve by going to the newline character. Eg.:

> what is the fastest way to delete the end of the line character?

Just hit `J` to **j**oin the lines. (If you have `autoindent` or friends enabled, that will even take care of removing indentation from the joined line for you.) Follow up with an `x` if you didn’t want the extra space character you just got; or use `gJ` to begin with, instead.

Comment: +1: Good explanation.  You can also use `gJ` instead of `Jx` to join without a space (has the advantage of being a single operation, so `.` will repeat the join rather than the character delete).

Comment: Ah, nice. I had not stumbled into that one. I’ve amended my answer correspondingly.

Comment: I disagree, because I have a use case where I want to go past the last character: it is to make a macro behave consistently.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: that lacks too much detail to answer usefully.

Comment: @AristotlePagaltzis Indeed. This was a use case from real life, where I was writing a macro to replace certain occurrences of `v1 - v2` with `subtract(v1, v2)`. It was based on first selecting the `v1 - v2` using the mouse, then invoking the macro. The problem is that `\`>` takes the cursor *after* the last character normally, but not when it's the last character on the line — then it goes just before the last character. So the macro chops off the last character in that case. With `:set ve=onemore`, it works consistently.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the sequence '`A` `Del` `ESC`' to delete the newline character from a line.

> A: Append after line

more information can be found here:
http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html

Answer (score 1):

It is just annoying that when you learn vi/vim, most people out there tell you to type `"i"` to start insert mode, but almost all skip telling what is basic "editing" because of how other editors do it. (and many are not aware of this until too late, and maybe ashamed to admit in public, I am not)

in command mode, you go ahead and find a location/character where your cursor blinks, and you are given 3 editing choices:

- `"i"` - edit before that character (insert, continue editing until you hit ESC)
- `"r"` - edit at that character (replace, one-time action, returns to command mode immediately )
- `"a"` - edit after that character (append, continue editing until you hit ESC)

so, using `"l"`, `"$"` or `"END"` keys takes you only to the last character. there, you decide the fate of editing, and it is `"a"` to continue editing in the case we got here. the remaining part is to press ESC after editing is done.

---

EDIT: adding to `i,r,a`, it is also possible to use their capitalized versions, by `SHIFT` or `CAPS LOCK`.

- `I` - jump to the beginning of the line and start inserting until ESC
- `R` - start continuously replacing until ESC
- `A` - jump to the end of the line after the last character and start appending until ESC

here in the situation of this question, `A` would be much preferable.