# How do I make $ go to end of line for Vim instead of just last-1?

Tags: vim

How do I make $ go to end of line for Vim instead of just last-1?

I know that GA works, but I like $ and I would like it go last.

Also, how do I make it so that if I move right at the end of a line, it automatically goes to the next line down all the way on the left like other editors?

Comment: `$` already goes to the last character. See `:help 'whichwrap' for your second question.

Comment: I want it to go the end though, which is always one more character to the right

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical vim cursor in command mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904949/vertical-vim-cursor-in-command-mode)

Answer (score 2):

This is not typical vim flow. Read [Move to the end of line character in Vi, past the last character in the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664924/move-to-the-end-of-line-character-in-vi-past-the-last-character-in-the-line)

But if you still want this feature there is a way.

There is `virtualedit` option for moving to places where there is no actuall characters.

```
:h virtualedit
```

> Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is
>       no actual character.  This can be halfway into a tab or beyond the end
>       of the line.  Useful for selecting a rectangle in Visual mode and
>       editing a table.

So all you have to do is set

```
set virtualedit=onemore
```

> onemore:  Allow the cursor to move just past the end of the line

**Update** after @LievenKeersmaekers comment

You also will need to update your mappings so your `$` will go after last char

```
 nnoremap $ $l
```

Comment: This might be what OP actually wants but `$` will still just jump to the last character. He'll need `$l` to get beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go to the end of the line to start inserting new text, press `"A"` (capital). this will place the cursor after the last character and activate `INSERT` mode.

for the purpose of adding new text, it is unfortunate that almost all sources tell about only `"i"`, but there are 2 more of them, `"r"` and `"a"`, and their capitalized versions, `I, R, A`: insert before, replace at, append after.